# Constantly redirecting after n seconds

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, time

I have a list of urls that I would like to open in a popup for say 10 seconds. So I click a button and it will open the first url then wait 10 seconds and play the next and so on until it's over. 
I have found a few functions that I thought would work or help and I thought my logic was right and thought it should work but maybe someone with more knowledge can help me out. This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function Redirect(url) {
        popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=481,width=858,left=10,top=10,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no')

    }

    function newPopup() {
        <?php 
        $jsSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `songs`"); 
        while($jsRow = mysql_fetch_array($jsSql))
        {?>
            setTimeout('Redirect("<?php
            echo "http://www.youtube.com/embed".$jsRow['url']."?autoplay=1";?>")', 4000);
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: **mysql_*** is **DEPRECATED** use PDO or MySQLi

Comment: 1) show the rendered html 2) write a fiddle 3) what does not work? The popping? The redirect? Popup blocker active?

Comment: I have been trying those suggestions and sorry I can't supply code as I'm not at my work PC but the suggestions don't seem to be working. My thought was that doesn't javascript and php run at different times essentially never populating my array with php output? If that is not a problem I will keep at it and try to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function Redirect(url) {
        window.open(url, 'popUpWindow', 'height=481,width=858,left=10,top=10,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
    }

    function newPopup() {
        <?php
            $stmt   = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `songs`");
            $songs  = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            foreach($songs AS $index => $song) {
                printf("setTimeout(Redirect('http://www.youtube.com/embed%s?autoplay=1'), 4000);", $song->url);
            }
        ?>
    }

    // Start
    newPopup();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
setTimeout('Redirect("<?php
  echo "http://www.youtube.com/embed".$jsRow['url']."?autoplay=1";?>")', 4000);
```

to

```
setTimeout(function() {
   Redirect("<?php
     echo "http://www.youtube.com/embed".$jsRow['url']."?autoplay=1";?>")}, 4000);
```

would be a good start

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
            var data = [];
            var current = 0;
            <?php 
            while($jsRow = mysql_fetch_array($jsSql))
                echo "data.push($jsRow['url']);";
            ?>

            function Redirect()
            {

            }

            function newPopup()
            {
                Redirect(data[current]);    
                current++;
                if (current < data.length)
                    setTimeout(function(){newPopup();}, 10*1000)    
            }
```

All you have to do is to call newPopup for the first time on some event. You mention button click.
The code also check if there are no more items to play.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this issue is that after you open the popup window with the first URL, you then want to just set the `window.location` on the existing popup window so that it just loads a new URL.  So, it would be something like this:

```
// globals
var songList;

function openNewPopup(url) {
    return window.open(url, 'popUpWindow','height=481,width=858,left=10,top=10,
         resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,
         location=no,directories=no,status=no');
}
```

Then, for subsequent page loads into that existing popup window, you just

```
function setNewPopupURL(url, popup) {
   popup.location = url;
}
```

I don't really know PHP, but you'd want to put the list of songs into a JS variable that you can later loop over:

```
// populate the songList
// the goal here is to do songList.push(songURL) for each song
// to add them all to the songList
<?php 
$jsSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `songs`"); 
while($jsRow = mysql_fetch_array($jsSql))
{?>
    songList.push("<?php
    echo "http://www.youtube.com/embed".$jsRow['url']."?autoplay=1";?>");
<?php
}
?>
```

And, then you can start the popup rotation by calling a function like this:

```
function runPopup() {
    var index = 0;
    var popup = openNewPopup(songList[index++]);

    function next() {
        setNewPopupURL(songList[index % songList.length), popup);
        ++index;
        setTimeout(next, 10*1000);
    }
    setTimeout(next, 10*1000);
}
```